# Maintain focused Item in List under React + Flux architecture

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have one list of items, and I have a `div` for showing the detail of item as well. For example,

```
--------------------------------------------
| Items List  |  Selected Item Detail      |
--------------------------------------------
| Item A      |   Item C is selected       |
| Item B      |   Item C is a cool         |
| Item C*     |                            |
| Item D      |                            |
--------------------------------------------
```

And my components are:

```
- AppContainer
  - Item List
    - Item
  - Selected Item Detail
```

The AppContainer has the following stats

- `allItems`
- `selectedItemId`

Here comes my question: is the implementation correct?

1. Should I maintain `selectedItemId` (an integer) in AppContainer, and find the corresponding item by the id when passing selected item to **Selected Item Detail**?
2. Or should I keep a `selectedItem` (an object) as state, and pass it to **Selected Item Detail** directly?
3. Should I keep the `selectedItem` or `selectedItemId` in Flux's Store? (given I keep the `allItems` in Store after using Flux in my application.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your questions suggest, there are multiple ways to achieve the same thing, so I think it's not a matter of *is the implementation correct* so much as *which implementation makes the most sense*.

> Should I maintain selectedItemId (an integer) in AppContainer, and
>   find the corresponding item by the id when passing selected item to
>   Selected Item Detail? Or should I keep a selectedItem (an object) as
>   state, and pass it to Selected Item Detail directly?

I think in general it's preferable to keep the state as compact as possible and *derive* data that depends on other data where it's actually needed. There's also the old DRY standard of 'don't repeat yourself.' Since the selected item can be derived from the set of all items and the index, I would store the index rather than an extra copy of the item.

> Should I keep the selectedItem or selectedItemId in Flux's Store?
>   (given I keep the allItems in Store after using Flux in my
>   application.)

For the same reasons as above, I would store the ID rather than a copy of the item.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. For the second question, my point is actually that "if I save ID, then should I save it in store or in component's own state?".

Comment: It seems like use of component state is generally discouraged when using flux, but there are some exceptions like form inputs where it makes sense to keep it scoped to the component. It's basically a question of whether it represents "application state", meaning, is this bit of state potentially relevant to other components besides the one where it originates? In this case it is, since you're selecting the ID in Item or ItemList but it's used by SelectedItemDetail, so I would save it in the store.